Continuous Dynamic Routing and Scheduling in a Network with Constraints
I am attempting to solve a scheduling and routing problem in a network. The graph and its properties are described subsequently.
Each node has a letter label, one constant value (capability), and one variable value (used). The capacity value represents the limit we want to avoid exceeding, and the used value represents how much has been consumed. The used value increases continuously until it has been reset by a network-bound machine called a Reset Machine.
The used value of a node can exceed its capacity value, at which point we are operating at a deficit - this should be avoided as much as possible. The expectation is that the Reset Machine resets the used values that are close to or have exceeded the capability value of their associated nodes.
The distances between the nodes are represented as numerical values. The machine can move bidirectionally between the nodes.
The goal is to develop a non-ending route that determines which nodes the machine should visit next while ensuring that all nodes are eventually visited.
The following constraints must be considered:

Minimized deficit operation of the nodes ('used' > 'capacity')
Minimize total distance travel, so that nodes close to each other a likely to be reset first.

Not that the resetting process costs time and energy, therefore, we don't expect the machine to reset every node on its path. Which means it can skip nodes.
Approaches I've considered:

Use shortest-path algorithms - we don't have a destination, the solution needs to be continuous.
Develop an algorithm to determine the next node, after each node visit. This will work to some extent, however, we still need to ensure that all nodes are eventually visited. A more holistic approach may be beneficial.

Any suggestion on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated. I'd prefer the code to be in Python, however, pseudo code, solution framework, and any other form of suggestions are greatly appreciated.
